# An error occurs in the react useSWR type definition

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I get an error in token and api part. I don't know why it happens.

```
    const token = 'aaa'
    const fetchWithToken = (url: string, token: string) => 
    axios.get(url, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
            withCredentials: true 
        })
        .then(result => result.data);

 const { data: ProductDetail } = useSWR<ProductInfo>([`/goods?lim=8`, token], fetchWithToken, {
        dedupingInterval: 1000000,
    })
```

After declaring the ProductInfo type, I put token and fetchWithToken functions in the api.

but ([`/goods?lim=8`, token], fetchWithToken, {
dedupingInterval: 1000000,
})
Here's the error with a red underline.

```
Argument of type '[string[], (url: string, token: string) => Promise<unknown>, { dedupingInterval: number; }]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly [Key] | readonly [Key, Fetcher<ProductInfo> | null] | readonly [Key, Partial<PublicConfiguration<ProductInfo, any, Fetcher<ProductInfo>>> | undefined] | readonly [...]'.
  Type '[string[], (url: string, token: string) => Promise<unknown>, { dedupingInterval: number; }]' is not assignable to type 'readonly [Key, Fetcher<ProductInfo> | null, Partial<PublicConfiguration<ProductInfo, any, Fetcher<ProductInfo>>> | undefined]'.
    Type at position 1 in source is not compatible with type at position 1 in target.
      Type 'Promise<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'ProductInfo | Promise<ProductInfo>'.
        Type 'Promise<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<ProductInfo>'.
          Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ProductInfo'.ts(2345)
```

I couldn't solve this problem, so I tried removing the ProductInfo type, but ProductDetail is not
It is output as an unknown values.

how can i solve it?
I do not know.